# Need to get JSON data locally and use AJAX to put the data into 3 separate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is my Javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('/sections.json', function(data){

var items = [];

$.each(data, function(key, value){

    items.push('<li id= " ' + key +' ">)' + val + '</li>');
});

$('<ul/>' , {
  'class':' title',
  html: items.join('')
}).appendTo('#services');
  });
});
```

this is the part of the html file that i want to append the info into

```
<section id="services">
    <div id="web" class="box">
     </div>

    <div id="ecomm" class="box">
    </div>

    <div id ="mobile" class="box">
    </div>
</section>
```

My script sources:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">    <\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

This is the json DATA

```
[
{
    "title": "Website Development",
    "details": "Custom websites and easy-to-use content management solutions that are scalable, robust and cross browser compatible. Our team has knowledge and experience in all web technologies.",
    "image": "web-design.png",
    "url": "#web-design"
},
{
    "title": "eCommerce Solutions",
    "teaser": "Our team will collaborate with you to understand your online objectives and goals, using that information to build a secure and reliable web-based storefront.",
    "image": "ecommerce.png",
    "url": "#ecommerce"
},
```

more JSON DATA

```
{
    "title": "Mobile Phone applications",
    "teaser": "Our team specializes in developing mobile applications and websites that deliver on quality, performance and speed.",
    "image": "mobile.png",
    "url": "#mobile"
}
]
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Call your divs with jQuery and apply the HTML you want:
$("#myDiv").html("the replacement text")

You will want to format the string with the JSON you indicated, but the idea is similar to that which you used for the unordered lists (which I assume you understand and wrote since you didn't leave a source for it).

I am not quite sure WHAT your question is based on what you wrote; please specify if this doesn't help.